# The ArrayList .add method does not work within a thread

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've tried to get a String from the request function and add it to the lastList ArrayList, but it will not be added normally.

In this case, how can I add?

As a global variable public ArrayList  lastList = new ArrayList <> (); But it did not work.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Task runned.");
            for (int i = 0; i < alarmList.size(); i++) {
                final String str[] = alarmList.get(i).split("#!%~#");
                for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
                    try {
                        final String output = AddActivity.request(str[1], str[2]);
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                if (Integer.parseInt(str[3]) == Integer.parseInt(StringUtils.substringBetween(output, str[1] + " ", "화"))) {
                                    lastList.add(output);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "OK");
                        break;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Exception.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    try {
        thread.join();

        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "thread end.");
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Size: " + lastList.size()); // Size: 0
        }
```

I expect the output of Size: 1, but the actual output is Size: 0.

Comment: Are you sure that thread started with `handler.post()` already finished when you call `size()` on your list?

Comment: Yes, I called size () after confirming that the thread was completed through the thread.join () function.

Comment: No, you are joining with one thread, put you are passing  another `Runnable` to `handler.post()` which I think will be executed in one more thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is `handler` in your code, but seems like it makes http POST and then callback is executed in another thread after POST response. So, as I understand, you are making join on the thread `thread`, but you are updating the list in another thread which is executed in POST callback. Since http call normally takes much longer then executing several lines of code, you don't see your list updated. To be sure - try to put `Tread.sleep(10000)` after `thread.join()`; and check if the size is 1. Also, putting some debug log statements would be really helpful here, put some log line after this `lastList.add(output)`, so you can see the sequence of execution.

Then you can, probably, fix it by making join on your callback thread as well.

Just to demonstrate the idea I came up with this test code:

```
static Thread innerThread;
static ArrayList lastList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Thread main: started.");

  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("Thread thread: started.");

      innerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("Thread innerThread: started.");
          try {
            System.out.println("Thread innerThread: sleeping for 1 second.");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          lastList.add("test");
          System.out.println("Thread innerThread: value added to the lastList");
          System.out.println("Thread innerThread: ended.");
        }
      });
      innerThread.start();
      System.out.println("Thread thread: ended.");
    }
  });

  thread.start();
  try {
    thread.join(); // to be sure that thread is finished - innerTread is initialized
    innerThread.join(); // to be sure that innerTread is finished - lastList is updated

    System.out.println("Thread main: lastList.size() = " + lastList.size()); // Size: 1
  } catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("Thread main: ended.");
}
```

Output:

```
Thread main: started.
Thread thread: started.
Thread thread: ended.
Thread innerThread: started.
Thread innerThread: sleeping for 1 second.
Thread innerThread: value added to the lastList
Thread innerThread: ended.
Thread main: lastList.size() = 1
Thread main: ended.
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:

```
 handler.post(new Runnable() {
```

makes your:

```
 lastList.add(output);
```

execute after your logging:

```
 Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Size: " + lastList.size()); // Size: 0
```

From your code its not clear why you need to use `handler.post`, its mostly used when you need to update UI widgets from worker thread.